# Change getusermedia stream resolution after it is already created

Tags: javascript, reactjs, getusermedia, mediastream

I have a React app that records the user's webcam I'm implementing a feature to allow the user to change the video resolution. When I create the `Media Stream` for the first time passing a default video's width and height it works fine, however when I change the resolution nothing happens I'm still able to record the webcam but the resolution does not change. The following code is used to get the `Media Stream`, the `width` and `height` variables could be `1280x720` or `640x360`. The default value mentioned above is `1280x720` and I can't change it to `640x360` after I the stream is created, if I create the stream using the `640x360` it works though.

```js
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: {
          width: {
            ideal: width
          },
          height: {
            ideal: height
          },
          frameRate: 25,
          deviceId: { exact: videoInputId || cameraDeviceId },
          aspectRatio: {
            exact: width / height,
          },
        },
        audio: audio,
});
cameraVideoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
setCameraStream(stream);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `getUsermedia()` again, with new constraints, to get a new `stream` object with a new resolution from a browser's camera.  For best results close the old stream object first, by stopping all its tracks.